# Before exporting i need to insert data from one table to another table-php

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel

I have created temporary table -`temporary_ticket`

I want to insert data from main table to temporary table `ticket`

Before exporting data i need to insert data from main table to temporary table and then exclude unwanted columns

Here is my sql code.

```
$sql = "SELECT id,subject,created_by,type,status,cat_id,DATE_FORMAT(create_time, '%m/%d/%Y 00:00:00')as create_time ,DATE_FORMAT(update_time, '%m/%d/%Y 00:00:00')as update_time,priority,updated_by,assigned_to,ticket_type,agent_created,cust4 FROM  `$DB_TBLName` ORDER BY id ASC";
```

I tried

```
Insert* INTO temporary_ticket  FROM ticket /* Drop the cloumns that are not needed */
ALTER TABLE temporary_ticket  DROP COLUMN guest_name,guest_email /* Get results and drop temp table */
SELECT * FROM temporary_ticket DROP TABLE temporary_ticket
```

but its not coming

Anything wrong in this query?

Here is my complete code

```
<?php
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "*****"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "******";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "i******";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "wp3_wpsp_ticket"; //MySQL Table Name   
$filename = "Support Ticket_Export";         //File Name


$sql="insert into wp3_wpsp_temporary_ticket  
      SELECT *   FROM wp3_wpsp_ticket 
      commit;" 


$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());

//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");


 $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
 //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
 for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
 echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
 }
 print("\n");   

 //end of printing column names  
 //start while loop to get data
 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
 {
  $schema_insert = "";
  for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
   if(!isset($row[$j]))
    $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
    elseif ($row[$j] != "")
    $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
    else
    $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
    }   
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL [select ... into ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) is not used for populating tables based another table, this statement is used for assigning values to variables or exporting data into external files.

You need to use [insert ... select ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) statement instead:

```
insert into temporary_ticket
select * from ticket
```

However, the series of statements that you described in your question can be simply replaced by a

```
select <list of fieldnames excluding guest_name,guest_email) from ticket
```

statement. No need for temporary table creation and all the other complicated stuff.

Comment: Your insert ... select ... statement does not comply with the MySQL syntax, pls check my answer again for the correct syntax. I still do not see the point of the whole temporary table creation, a simple select from the ticket table can reproduce the expected outcome.

Comment: You mean select(excluding guest_name,guest_email,) from ticket

Comment: Yep, that's right. But you need to manually list the fields in the query that you need to include.

Comment: SELECT (guest_name,guest_email)FROM  `$DB_TBLName` ORDER BY id ASC";
this query is not working for me

Comment: As I wrote several times: you need to manually list all the fields you want to include in the select. There is no exception, or anything like that. This is basic sql.

Comment: if i include all fieldshere ,in the future again if i want to add any new field?  i need to edit it. that is not the right way

Comment: Your table structure should not really change after your system went live. If your table structure changes you may want to exclude that field from the report, so you may have to change your query anyway. I think you have extremely off-the-rocker expectations as to how an rdbms works. There are ways to dynamically query the fields of a table and you can create an sql statement from your php code that has all the required fields. This is still faster, than trying to copy an entire table, delete a few fields from it, and then just return all data from that table.

Answer (score 1):

You should use  insert select

```
insert into temporary_ticket  
SELECT *   FROM ticket ;
```

and be sure your columns between the two table match for type and number  (same sequence too)

Comment: i tried but its not getting inserted into temporary table

Comment: show  your temporary_ticket  and ticket schema please  (update your question)

Comment: Almost both are same

Comment: @JMR   they must muct for number and type fo columns

Comment: @JMR and ticket  table ? are exactly the same  ?

Comment: Then if the table are the same this mean that the ticket table is empty or that you don't have autocommit set to true  then you must commit

Comment: Ticket table is not empty...it contains data ....I need to check with auto commit

Comment: You can test the query  for sintax in sql console .. .. as you can see the query in my answer don't use php vars inside the sql code  so should be the same .. (check also if you are correcly connected to db)

Comment: then update you question an show a bit more code  ... starting with you connection to db until the end of insert . --- Are you sure you don't have error executing your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125916/discussion-between-jmr-and-scaisedge).

Comment: i need to exclude some of the columns ....but first i need to insert data into temporary table

Comment: Try var_dump($result) ;
(you can also remove the commit at the end of the query ... i think that wp is auto_commit enabled

Comment: And remove the @   before the mysql_quey  ... the @ silent the error ...

Comment: all the @ or only $result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect)

Comment: $result = mysql_query($sql,$Connect) ... only this row .. at least

Comment: Couldn't execute query:
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
1136

Comment: Well .. we now have found the error .. (this beacuse the @ hide the message error from db)  .. then  you should check column by column that the type is corresponding .. could be that the two table have not the same column definition .  . can't see no more the table so ... i can check myself

Comment: you mean that atleast column names should be different

Comment: Not the column name  .. but the number and column type, (and the sequence of type in the column) .. the name is not important but if the corresponding column is of the same type  ..is mandatory

Comment: sorry i didn't get you ....i have gone through some of the answers but they say all the fields and type should be same if you are moving to any other table.can you please elaborate

Comment: the number and the type of the column in select and in insert must by the same this mean that each column must macth the type of the correspondenting column  in you case you have a insert into table_name select * from another_table_name .. this mean that all the column of the first table must match the type of the second table and must to be in the same number  .. hope is clear ..

Comment: yes i am clear ...i have some data already inserted in main table... it may not me matching the number...so i need todrop all data from table or insert some data into temporary table

Comment: You should be sure that the two table definition match .. but another important  element is that in your message you have "Column count doesn't match value count " this mean that eg: you  are select 3 column but you are inserting for 4 or the opposite .. check also this ..